# When using Vue3 composition api and vuex together, how can I separate the function that changes state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
<!-- SelectColor.vue -->
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { storeData } from "./common";

let { resultColor } = storeData();
const props = defineProps({
  selectType: String,
});
const store = useStore();
const changeSelect = (e) => {
  store.commit("resultColor/updateResultColor", {
    type: props.selectType,
    value: e.target.value,
  });
};
const selectedOption = (type) => {
  return props.selectType == type;
};
</script>
```

I separated the code to get the state of the store as below and put it in a different file.

```
//common.js
import { computed, reactive, toRefs } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

const storeData = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  let state = reactive({
    count: computed(() => store.state.count.count),
    resultColor: computed(() => store.state.resultColor.resultColor),
    resultList: computed(() => store.state.count.result),
  });
  return toRefs(state);
};

export { storeData };
```

Like this, I want to separate this code.↓

```
const store = useStore();
const changeSelect = (e) => {
  store.commit("resultColor/updateResultColor", {
    type: props.selectType,
    value: e.target.value,
  });
};
```

I don't want to use the useStore repeatedly. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Composable `use` functions are supposed to be used directly in `setup` function, or in the case of `<script setup>`, at the top level of the tag. The usage in other places depends on function implementation and needs to be confirmed.

`useStore` is generally used once per component:

```
import { useStore } from "vuex";

const store = useStore();
...
```

In case the code doesn't reside inside a component, a store can be imported directly:

```
import store from '...';
```

In this case this can be XY problem because if `storeData` needs to be constantly restuctured, this means that the store was incorrectly designed. Reactive object that `state` contains could be a getter inside the store, because it only involves up-to-date store data.

Comment: Since we're importing the store/file directly, is there any way to call the dispatch method? Since it's a function from the useStore object, which were not using in this case. Or is this a better way to update the state?

Comment: There's no separate "useStore object", it's the same `store`. It can be used as `store.dispatch`, dispatch and commit functions are legit ways to modify a state. Can you clarify about a getter?